# Previously user already login, so how i can take user to direct their dashboard?

Tags: php, session, authentication

After user first time register and login, if user do not logout, then when user visit next time, how can I log in user automatically, so he do not need to login again. I think it can be handled via session, but how can i do it? Please help me or provide some tutorial. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a cookie on the users PC [php.setcookie](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)

Answer (score 1):

First of all if you just need login then session is enough but if you mean that user shouldn't be asked for login again then you might wanna go for cookies.

**For session**

- Validate User And Set Session variables
- For each request check if corresponding session values exit.

**For Cookies**

- When the user logs into your website.
- Store a cookie on his/her system.
- For each user login first check if there is any cookie on user's system that you already stored.

For tutorial check this [link](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL)

Answer (score 0):

On login function validate & then create

```
 $_SESSION['isLogged'] =1
```

or you can assign username too, as session is stored in server there is no harm in doing that

```
 $_SESSION['username']=$username;
```

then in login page simply use :

```
if( $_SESSION['isLogged'] ==1)
header("Location: dashboard.php");
```

Example login.php

```
<?PHP
session_start();
if( isset($_SESSION['isLogged']) && $_SESSION['isLogged'] ==1)
 header("Location: dashboard.php");

if(!isset($_POST['user'])){
?>
<form method="post" action="">
<input name="user" type="text"/>
<input name="password" type="password"/>
<input name="login" type="submit"/>
</form>
<?PHP
}else{
if(isValid($_POST['user'],$_POST['password'])){
    $_SESSION['username']=$_POST['user'];
    $_SESSION['isLogged'] =1;
    header("Location: dashboard.php");
}else{
   echo "incorrect !";
}
?>
```